# MBPr Yosemite – USB speakers to external (mini displayport) display not showing as an output option

Tags: display, usb, displayport, speakers

I have a Bose USB 2.1 system. When I plug it into my MBPr directly, I have the option to output sound to "Bose USB Audio" and it works beautifully. I just got a new monitor, (a Dell U2415,) and if I plug the speakers into the USB ports on the monitor, it doesn't show up as an output option. I'm trying to set up a home workstation that I can plug in and out of easily – I would love for both the speakers and monitor to work with just the mini displayport plug instead of having to plug/unplug both the mini displayport and a USB every time.

Why don't the speakers work when plugged into the monitor USB, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the initial USB cable from computer to screen? Did you try connecting after boot? My Dell monitors' USB is slow to startup at boot & won't even recognise keyboard & mouse at that point.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't have a USB from the computer to monitor, just mini displayport. (is that necessary? kind of defeats the whole purpose of having USBs on the monitor, doesn't it?) I just tried connecting after boot and no luck.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you have to have the upstream USB connected. Bummer. Thanks though! http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN145032/EN